# how to get strings from curly brackets?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I would need help: 
I have an array and I need to get values from it...but how to get the data which are within curly brackets ...

It should be something simple, I think ... I tried with explode which obviously cannot work as I have for example within last curly brackets with two kinds of data, which should be distinguished as so...each curly bracket (with data applies to something).

```
$array = array(
  "other" => "{name:2},{value:2},{align:4},{height:4, color:red}",
  "another" => "{name:2},{value:2},{align:4},{height:4, color:red}"
);
```

I'm really struggling ... and appreciate your help. 
Thanks

Comment: the format is like json, but it should be treated as in the form above ... so I think all the data in {} should be extracted from this string and afterwards explode them by ','

Comment: what about preg_match using comma as separator if it is not within brackets? but I'm not sure how to do that ...

Comment: I'm **WORRIED:** how to make both your answers as valid - @Tim and D. Rattansingh?

Comment: @D. Rattansingh I would like to make your and Tim's answer as accepted ... just don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, I think explode will work perfectly. Explode into separate strings and then for each string retrieve from index 1 to index [arraylength-1] since index 0 contains { and the last index contains }.

`$str = substr($str, 1, strlen($str)-1);`

So for each string cut out from index 1 to last_index-1.

EDIT:

AFter you do the first explode (which will cut it into 2 big chunks): chunk1 and chunk2

`foreach chunk array
$pieces=explode(",",$chunk1);` // or chunk 2 (this will further cut the pieces up into strings that were separated by ,)

`$str = substr($pieces, 1, strlen($pieces)-1);`

Then for each $piece, retrieve the content in between. (pseudo code)

Comment: sorry, it does not :S explode works fine - but extracts all data separated by comma, which is not ok, as the values separated by comma within curly brakets has to be still somehow treated together

Comment: AFter you do the first explode (which will cut it into 2 big chunks), take the pieces INDIVIDUALLY (i.e. a chunk at a time) and do another explode: $pieces=explode(",",$strPiece); (this will further cut the pieces up into strings that were separated by ,) Then for each $piece, use the code I gave above and will retrieve the content in between.

Comment: Please note I wrote pseudo-code for the above but its gives the idea

Comment: ooooo! thank you so much ... really works .. I tried before, maybe I did something wrong and when I get data split, I can use Tim's code to extract all from {} THANKS!

Comment: Hey check my ans as correct. Since i've been here no one ever did that

Comment: you are right - this was also the most tricky part for myself. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match_all('/\{([^}]*)\}/', $str, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match)
{
    $pieces = explode(',', $match);
    foreach($pieces as $pair)
    {
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', trim($pair));
        // do something with $key and $value
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain exactly what that does.

Comment: yes, I tried this ... but I was thinking that I missed something out and maybe there's another way ...

Comment: I agree more with `haynar`s answer, because the example given is `JSON` encoded, so you should be using `json_decode(...)`.

Comment: Other issue: I think I need to get an array of values which are separated by comma ... and afterwards do it with preg_match_all (this does not work in my case)

Comment: Tim, thank you very much - it works with the D. Rattansingh's code ... and perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

try this, and read about `json_decode` and `json_encode` funcitons

```
$result = json_decode('['.$array['other'].']', true);
```

**UPDATE**

after trying this, I've noticed that your string is not a valid JSON, so my answer is not a good solution until you can get {"key":"value"} format

Comment: Is ```{name:2}``` valid JSON?  Doesn't it need to be ```{'name':2}```?  I may be wrong, or PHP may be relaxed about it.

Comment: `{name: 2}` is not invalid, but `{color: red}` is really invalid and I noticed that only now

Comment: {name: 2} is invalid too.  See [example #3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: I agree - it is alike json format and I did in one of my versions, but I'm supposed to treated this as regular array ... because if I put everything in json format it's been said to me it would be too complicated ...

Comment: so if you could get `{"key":"value"}` format, it your goal could be easily achieved with `json_decode`

Comment: yes, you are right ... but it was said - to keep this format and I'm lost :S

Comment: so .. even if I change to json ... doesn't work .. I tried to change also curlies to squares ... if I put in the real json format it is not accepted by my client :S like it is to many [] there ...